# Flutter: Thermal Receipt printing via USB in Android devices

Tags: flutter, dart, thermal-printer, usbserial

I am looking for a plugin or a native Kotlin/Java code to implement printing thermal receipts from Thermal printers which USB connects to Android devices.

Currently, I have tried many available plugins in pub.dev but no luck.